# VBA Getting data from another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Currently i am trying to get data from another sheet, on the current sheet a user types dates they want to get. I am getting a syntax error though, when i try to get the data.
This is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Fund As String, Start, EndD As Date


Fund = Range("B4")
Start = Range("B5")
EndD = Range("B6")
Dim rngS As Range
Dim rngE As Range

   Set rngS = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000").Find(Start, lookat:=xlPart)
    Set rngE = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000").Find(EndD, lookat:=xlPart)
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("rngS.Address:rngE.Address").Copy Destination:=Sheets("mySheet01").Range("A8")



End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from `Range("rngS.Address:rngE.Address")` and put this: `Range(rngS.Address & ":" & rngE.Address)`

Comment: Thanks!! I was looking at it for a good 10 min, didn't realise that was all it needed